# iOS Share Extension cannot find Swift classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, share

I'm trying to import 'Swift' class into my 'Obj C' project, but 'Share extension' cannot find that specific class when I import it. Is there some workaround to import it or simply writing a 'Swift' class in 'Obj C' as a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand what your problem is, but have you defined a bridging header? See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html for details

Comment: Check that you have included the file in the target. Like so: http://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Z0A.jpg

Comment: I've tried, but I want to import Swift file into Objective C file and use it. Sorry if I didn't configure question correctly.

Comment: @Sealos I've included, but still no success. [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/1d5d285ca2.png)

Comment: Are you sure that's the target name? Should be something like "myApp_Share_Extension-Swift.h".

Comment: Name of the Share_Extension is like that, but I want to use Swift file from base in my Share_Extension. Note that extension is in Obj C. myApp-Swift.h is working in the project and I've defined Bridging-Header correctly. I want to add Share_Extension, but I have some methods that I want to use, but Share_Extension cant see the myApp-Swift.h file when I #import it.